# [Android]How to modify the fillColor of VectDrawable by java Code

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I want to modify the fillColor of the VectDrawable by java Code,
I cannot find any solution to modify it,

```
vector xml is like this
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:width="14dp" android:height="14dp" android:viewportWidth="42" android:viewportHeight="42">
    <path android:fillColor="#fffff" android:pathData=""/>
    <path android:fillColor="#000000" android:pathData=""/>
</vector>
```

[the vect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7s5iD.png)

Comment: You could try setting the tint, or using a color matrix, but you can't modify the content of a VectorDrawable at run time.

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in Android Development, so there may be better ways of doing this! But as a quick fix, you could do something like this:

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.<yourView>);
Drawable drawable = view.getBackground();
```

Then once you have the drawable you can set the tint, color filter, whatever else it is you may want to do.

```
drawable.setTint(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
```

I am not able to test this right now, so I may have made a mistake or two, but Android Studio's error messages should guide you through fixing that. You may also have to call view.setBackground(drawable) to apply the changes. I am not sure if it will be updated automatically.